# How to "npm pack" an angular library through Java/Spring boot application?

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, angular-library

I have an angular project which has 5 common library made specific for our requirement.
I am using `com.github.eirslett` maven plugin in my spring boot application to build all the libraries via `pom.xml`which then gets copied to `dist/` folder. But I also want to pack those libraries because the path to those tarball (.tgz) file will be used in another application.
As of now I have to go one by one into all 5 folders inside `dist/` and run `npm pack` via cmd/terminal to create the `library_name.tgz` file.
Is there a way to automate that just like building the libraries ?
The maven plugin mentioned above is used widely everywhere but it doesn't support `npm pack` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

In package.json

```
"build-lib-name": "ng build lib-name",
"pack-lib-name": "cd dist/lib-name && npm pack",
"lib-name": "npm run build-lib-name && npm run pack-lib-name"
```

and in pom.xml, under `com.github.eirslett` plugin, I added this execution

```
                <execution>
                    <id>lib-name</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run lib-name</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
```